# How to make user input in java be of the type double?

Tags: java

This line:

```
arr[i] = sc.nextDouble();
```

from this code:

```
public class z01 { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    @SuppressWarnings("resource") 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter array size: "); 
    int n = sc.nextInt(); 
    double[] arr = new double[n]; 
    double min = 0; 
    for(double i = 0; i <n; i++){ 
      System.out.println("Enter element " + (i + 1)); 
      arr[i] = sc.nextDouble(); 
      if(i%3 == 0 && i <= min){ 
        min = i; 
      } 
    } 
    if(min != 0){ 
      System.out.println("The smallest number divisible by 3 is" + min); 
    } else { 
      System.out.println("No number is divisible by 3"); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Gives this warning:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int
```

How do I make user input in java be of the type double?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Your problem here is probably that the array arr is of type int. That is why you get that error. Define arr as follows and try again (where x the desired dimension):</strike>

```
double arr[] = new double[x];
```

The problem is that you have set `i` in the for loop to be of type `double` while it should be of type `int`

Comment: Then maybe perhaps `i` is double? Please give more information then.

Comment: public class z01 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter array size: ");
  int n = sc.nextInt();
  double[] arr = new double[n];
  double min = 0;
  for(double i = 0; i <n; i++){
   System.out.println("Enter element " + (i + 1));
   arr[i] = sc.nextDouble();
   if(i%3 == 0 && i <= min){
    min = i;
   }
  }
  if(min != 0){
  System.out.println("The smallest number divisible by 3 is" + min);
  }
  else{
   System.out.println("No number is divisible by 3");
  }
 }

}

Comment: As I said you have `i` declared as `double`. Make it `int`.

Comment: change `for(double i = 0; i <n; i++)` to `for(int i = 0; i <n; i++)`

Comment: Because array indexes have to be integers. You cannot access for example the 1.5 cell of an array because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use a try catch exception.

```
try {
     double var = sc.nextDouble();
} 
catch(TypeMismatchException ex) {
     System.err.println("try again, wrong type");
}
```

basically, if there is an error storing the value in a double, it'll execute the catch statement, and you can prompt the user again for more input.

Comment: tried it, but it gives the same warning plus one more ( TypeMismatchException cannot be resolved to 
  a type)

Comment: Then use Exception, because i'm not sure the specific one.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the following errors within your code:

- You are using a `double i` in your for-loop for being the array index, when you read in the array index to `int n`. That's where your Type Mismatch error is coming from. As array indexes must be of the type `int`, the `arr[i]` you have is attempting to pass an `arr[double]` where only `arr[int]` is supported.
- Your `min` needs to start at `Double.MAX_VALUE` if you want it to ever be re-assigned with the new minimum, unless you all entered values will be negative. Be sure to change your `if (min != 0) {` accordingly.